# Dynamodb: How do I efficiently query the number of rows in groups of primary keys?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamoDB table storing millions and millions of events

The table has a primary and a sort key:

```
Primary partition key   userID (Number)
Primary sort key    createdAt (String)
```

A table could look something like this:

```
userID  createdAt                       someAttr
374624  2017-04-17T20:16:41.695884945Z  abc
374624  2017-04-16T22:13:12.611114945Z  abc
374624  2017-04-20T20:18:15.695874945Z  abc
4046    2017-04-15T20:12:01.695814945Z  abc
4046    2017-04-17T20:16:22.195684945Z  abc
118898  2017-04-19T20:11:42.695874945Z  abc
4046    2017-04-17T20:14:41.192884945Z  abc
118898  2017-04-14T20:17:18.695784945Z  abc
118898  2017-04-13T20:03:41.295484945Z  abc
4046    2017-04-18T20:22:32.395784945Z  abc
118898  2017-04-30T20:08:41.595814945Z  abc
118898  2017-04-20T20:15:52.695784945Z  abc
```

In pseudo code I would like to query something like:

> Number of records for userIDs: 374624, 118898, 4046 within createdAt <
>   2017-04-19T00:00:00.000000001Z AND createdAt >
>   2017-04-16T00:00:00.000000001Z

Returning a result like his:

```
{
  374624 => 2,
  4046 => 3,
  118898 => 0
}
```

How can I do this efficiently with dynamoDB? Can I create an index that will make this easier for me to do?
What if I need to do it for 1000 userID's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DyanmoDB essentially provides two methods of accessing data. [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) can be used to access data by hash (partition) key, and for this reason it is fast. If you use query, you must specify one and only one hash key, meaning you can only retreive data from one partition with one query. You can optionally specify additional parameters to narrow down the results from within a partition. For example you can provide a range for your sort key.

> KeyConditionExpression
>
> The condition that specifies the key value(s)
> for items to be retrieved by the Query action.
>
> The condition must perform an equality test on a single partition key
> value.
>
> The condition can optionally perform one of several comparison tests
> on a single sort key value. This allows Query to retrieve one item
> with a given partition key value and sort key value, or several items
> that have the same partition key value but different sort key values.
>
> The partition key equality test is required, and must be specified in
> the following format:
>
> partitionKeyName = :partitionkeyval

The other options is [Scan.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html). A scan always evaluates every item in the table, so its typically slow and doesn't scale well. Using a scan you could get your data in one call, but it would be inefficient.

So in summary, you should do lots of Query calls, where each call has one hash key, and the conditions are the same in each Query. Then combine all of the results into one list.

EDIT: You can use [GetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html) to retrieve exactly one item by its (composite) primary key. And you can use [BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) to retrieve more than one item at a time. But there is no BatchQuery unfortunately.

Comment: So what you are saying is, sadly, that I cannot do what I wanna do with dynamo db. Can you think of any way I could do this more efficiently by making alternative indexes or something?

Comment: You can do it in DynamoDB for sure. You would just need to pass the range and partition keys to a bespoke function, which would iterate through the keys and do a Query for each, then add the results into one list and return that. Its not much code. But no, there is no way to do it in one call (other than a scan, which is likely to be slow and expensive). I don't think there are any quick work arounds - DynamoDB is just not intended to be as powerful as SQL. Its much faster in many cases though if used correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Query for each userId as your key conditions and filter by your sort keys with the projection only for your userIds, each query on dynamodb returns with a count: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Count
This is the most efficient way for what you want to do with this table structure.

Comment: Can you see other ways of structuring or indexing that could make this more performant (I would really like to not make 1k requests :-)